# Почему не работает file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, api, вконтакте

Мне нужно авторизованному пользователю показывать 5 его друзей, для этого написал такой код:

```
<?php
     $url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ХХХХХХХ&display=popup&scope=friends,offline&redirect_uri=http://мойсайт&response_type=code&v=5.92' ;
     $code = $_GET['code'];
     $url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=ХХХХХХХ&client_secret=секрет&code='.$code.'&redirect_uri=http://мой сайт';
     $result = file_get_contents($url);
     $result = json_decode($result, true);
     $access_token = $result['access_token'];
     $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=&order=random&count=5&fields=nickname, photo_50&access_token='.$access_token.'&v=5.92';
     $data = file_get_contents($url);
     $data = json_decode($data, true);
     var_dump ($data);
  ?>
```

В итоге VarDump выдаёт NULL. Перед этим file_get_contents отрабатывает хорошо. Если подставлять полученный access_token в ссылку и переходить через браузер, то показывает то, что нужно.

Перед `$data = json_decode($data, true); var_dump` пишет `bool(false)`.

---

В чем может быть проблема? 
Или может как-то по-другому надо реализовывать?

Comment: попробуйте пробел после запятой убрать в последнем $url

Comment: Нет, не помогло.) Начитал вот что проблема модет быть с хостером или у АПИ ВК какие то ограничения, хотя странно..